# How to sum a column based on date range --- Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV from which I need to sum the charges each month based the month the start_date falls within.

What's the best way to change `Coverage Start Date` to a date, and sum all charges in a given month using Pandas?

Here's how the data appears in the CSV:

```
Coverage Start Date     Coverage End Date       AMOUNT
20170902                20170930                0.37
20170905                20170930                11
20170815                20170831                0.37
20170909                20170930                0.37
```

Comment: 2 steps: 1) Use a converter (see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) corresponding to the column you want to modify, then extract the month, day, year info for the date, and finally convert it using datetime. 2) With your columns properly converted, you can do selections within a given frame, and then sum the prices in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `python3`,

```
data = {'Coverage Start Date': ['20170902', '20170905', `'20170815'],'Coverage End Date':['20170930', '20170930', '20170831'] , 'AMOUNT': [0.37, 11, 0.37]}`
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, convert into `datetime` index

```
df['Coverage End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Coverage End Date'])
df['Coverage Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Coverage Start Date'])
```

And then, create your starting date as index,

```
df = df.set_index(df['Coverage Start Date'])
```

And then use, `TimeGrouper`

```
new_df = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M')).sum()
```

Output,

```
                        AMOUNT
Coverage Start Date
2017-08-31               0.37              
2017-09-30               11.37
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the code by i.n.n.m. However to apply the date time function to multiple columns you can use the below

```
data = {'Coverage Start Date': ['20170902', '20170905', '20170815'],'Coverage End Date':['20170930', '20170930', '20170831'] , 'AMOUNT': [0.37, 11, 0.37]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(pd.to_datetime)

    AMOUNT  Coverage End Date   Coverage Start Date
0   0.37          2017-09-30            2017-09-02
1   11.00         2017-09-30            2017-09-05
2   0.37          2017-08-31            2017-08-15
```

And then go about grouping them!